# XTS Package v. 0.10-0 -- candles plot not working any more

Tags: r, plot, xts

Plot of xts data as a candles chart is not working in v. 0.10-0 while it was fine in the previous one :

```
data(sample_matrix)
plot(as.xts(sample_matrix), type='candles')
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can do this:

```
library(quantmod)
chart_Series(as.xts(sample_matrix))
```

Comment: I recommend you use `chart_Series()` for financial plots and charts.  The 'candle' type was not ported to `plot.xts()` because it's for a very specific type of time series data.

Comment: chart_Series does not work with any of the extra features in xts like addPolygon, addSeries, etc.

Comment: @kory Take a closer look. e.g. there is `add_Series`

Comment: @FXQuantTrader I see that now, thanks, but it is still missing addPolygon.  All I see is add_Shading.  Is there a way to use that in the same manner?  I use it to draw clouds between the prices in two series.